# Which statistic test/model is applicable?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, logistic, chi-squared-test, fishers-exact-test

I am currently working with medical data. I have created patient subsets if they fit certain characteristics, e.g. male & heigh >= 5 ft, female & height <= 6ft, etc...I am then comparing the independence of two categorical variables each with two levels: the response after treatment ('positive' or 'negative') and a certain characteristic related to the treatment, i.e. if the medical device is in the right location ('yes' or 'no'). I have been using Chi-Square and Fisher exact tests in each subset (e.g. male & height >= 5ft) to find if this characteristic of the treatment and the response after treatment are independent which has been meaningful, but I would like to compare the independence/relationship between these two categorical variables between the subsets.

My question: Is there a method/test to compare the results (p-value or odds ratio) of the Chi-square/Fisher exact test between these independent populations (e.g. male  & heigh >= 5 ft vs. female & height <= 6ft)? such as a test to compare the odds ratio between these two subsets?

If anyone has any R related implementations that would also be helpful.

Edit:
The data is a bit domain-specific, my subsets are not based on male/female and height, but based on specific characteristics related to a patient's heart. These subsets are created by binning patients based on two variables of interest analogous to male/female and a continuous variable like height. It is hypothesized, that in these subsets there is a difference in response to the treatment based on certain characteristics related to the treatment, e.g. if the medical device is in the right position.  Chi-Square tests make sense to analyze any given subset, i.e. is response independent of this treatment characteristic? But I am also interested in comparing this independence of response vs. device position between the subsets which are hypothesized to have differences.

Here is some example data. For example, I would want to compare subset1 and subset2 based on response and device position. Is there some method or test to compare something like the odds ratio (of response and device position) between these subsets?

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you might be losing a lot of information in the process of dichotomizing everything, as well as injecting some (perhaps a lot) of arbitrariness into the analysis.  Might I suggest you instead describe your data, tell us what you are trying to learn, and ask what might be a good method to analyze them?  Otherwise you put us in the difficult position of advising how to rescue a procedure that might be doomed from the start.

Comment: I find this long and difficult to follow: if you want to compare 25 out of 30 devices in the right place for Males >5ft vs. 20 out of 33  in the right place for Females < 6ft, then in R `prop.test(c(25,20), c(30,33), cor=F)` gives P-val 0.046 comparing proportions 0.8333 and  0.6061. // If you have another comparison in mind, please give appropriate counts with explanation.

Comment: @BruceET It is not just if the device is in the correct position, but also if the patient received a response to this treatment. The patients that go into this test comparing correct position vs. response are the different subsets, e.g. male >5ft. From the original data, I narrow the patients into a subset (criteria: male >5ft), then compare response vs. device position. This can be done using Chi-square or Fisher exact test, however, I would like to compare the results of these tests (e.g. odds ratio) or something similiar between these subsets.

Comment: Are you not able to provide counts and a forthright explanation what you are looking for? If that is the case, please respond to @whuber's Comment.

Comment: @whuber Can you check the edit. What specifically confuses you?

Comment: I am not confused: I am concerned, for the reasons I gave.  Your edit allays a bit of the second concern (arbitrariness) but does not address the principal concern about losing information through all the binning that is going on.  There are better ways to proceed--amply discussed in threads here about regression, model building, splines, and so on--that are likely to be superior *even when your ultimate goal is to develop a prediction based on the categories alone.*

Comment: @whuber There is a loss of information from binning, but that is not the focus of this analysis. I am simply creating subsets based on clinical guidelines which are standard practice. I can not change the binning, because I am interested in the differences between these subsets.

Comment: @whuber Logistic regression and spline are not applicable because if I model the target variable as a response to treatment, and use two predictors: the different subsets' device position ('correct position', 'wrong position') values. Then these subsets will have different lengths, since different numbers of patients fit into the different subsets.